# R Active Campagin API Access Pagination

Tags: r, pagination, activecampaign

I'm accessing Active Campaign via API, and I was able to access a particular list I want, but I just had access to the first 100 observations but they are 3,567.

I'm accessing the contacts that have associated determined tags, which are 8. Tags are in the string, but I'm accessing only 100. This is the code:

```
tag_id_string <- c(1197, 1230, 1235, 1256, 1257, 1275,1276,1278)
tag_ids_string2 <- paste(tag_id_string, collapse = ",") 
url_c <- paste0("https://cbsaust.api-us1.com/api/3/contacts?limit=100&tagid=",tag_ids_string2)

# Request res from API
res <- VERB("GET", 
            url_c, 
            add_headers(headers))

# Print the content of the response
content <- fromJSON(content(res, "text"),)
content <- content$contacts
```

How can I incrust this code into a for loop, so I insert each 100 on a database, until the last one?

Comment: Look at their documentation for pagination: https://developers.activecampaign.com/reference/pagination. You have hard coded `limit=100` into your URL. You will need to loop to change the `offset=` in the URL as well.